# How to say "such as" in Russian?

Tags: перевод, лексикон

As in, "today i want to talk about websites such as..." or "i like videos such as".  And also, the word "said" as in "said websites are good" or something.

Comment: "типа" ("like")

Comment: @Alexander I would sooner translate "типа" as "kinda":      
"I kinda like this kind of crap"

Comment: @Michael_1812 depending on context it can be either an adverb or a noun ( = "of  type such as").

Comment: @Alexander It sure can. The thing is that in the modern conversational Russian the former usage is rapidly taking over the latter one. Like in the joke about a new rich villain who lost his way in a forest and reluctantly shouts: "Ну, типа, ау..."

Comment: @Michael_1812 Maybe, but not to the point that old meaning is becoming obsolete. Given the context, the meaning of the whole phrase would still be unambiguous.

Comment: @Alexander  sure, not obsolete

Answer (score 4):

> Такой, как

Or, with your sentences:

> Сегодня я бы хотела поговорить о таких сайтах, как ...
>
> Мне нравятся такие видео, как ...

The word 'said' in such context is also 'такой(такие)' or 'этот(эти)' (this) or 'данный(данные)' (given/this).

The plural forms of those words are in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Literal translation is "такой, как", but a more natural way would be to omit that structure and just say "сегодня, я бы хотел поговорить о сайтах, которые (в которых / на которых)..." and "мне нравятся подобные видео".

As for the last one, you could say "подобные сайты - хорошие".

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the aforementioned "Такой, как" you can also use "Вроде". This is a more informal form and is more commonly used in daily speech. Your second example "I like movies such as" is perfect for it: "Мне нравятся фильмы вроде".